# cardView inside relativeLayout not showing contents in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Layout file

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_view"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apply wallet"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="PLACE ORDER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If i am moving the items of cardView and making parallel to recyclerView then only it is showing. In current case noting is displaying on screen, not even recyclerView items.

How to use cardView within relativeLayout?

Am i missing any android concept here?

Comment: Agarwal , hi there, kindly go through my answer and respond if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am using RecyclerView and CardView and it is pretty clean and standard way to make separate layouts for main activity and the items of recyclerView.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/GrayGood"
tools:context="faisal.example.recyclerview.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolBarContainer_ID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_ID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now layout for the items that will reside in your RecyclerView's row wrapped inside CardView.

activity_main_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardViewID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:clickable="true" //here make your recyclerItem row clickable 
android:focusable="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" //this will give you highlight effect when list item is pressed
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apply wallet"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="PLACE ORDER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, items will come overlapping over one another so set them by assigning layout_below="@+id/yourView"

This is the usual way of dealing with RecyclerView because you will need to use Layout of item's holder inside your RecyclerAdapter class.
Hope i have helped or guided.